# ImportError: cannot import name 'EntryView' from 'entries.views'

Tags: python, django

I am importing my views:

```
from .views import HomeView, EntryView
```

and the error I'm getting is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'EntryView' from 'entries.views' (. 
C:\Users\Kheri\dev\cfehome\blog\entries\views.py) */
```

Below I'm providing my files:

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Entry

class HomeView(ListView):
   model = Entry
   template_name = 'entries/index.html'
   context_object_name = "blog_entries"

   class EntryView(DetailView):
      model = Entry
      template_name = 'entries/entry_detail.html'
```

**urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomeView, EntryView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name = 'blog-home'),
    path('entry/<int:pk>/', EntryView.as_view(), name = 'entry-detail')
]
```

Comment: Is that the actual indentation? If yes, you must unindent `EntryView`. It is currently an inner class of `HomeView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try correcting the indentation of **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Entry

class HomeView(ListView):
   model = Entry
   template_name = 'entries/index.html'
   context_object_name = "blog_entries"

class EntryView(DetailView):
   model = Entry
   template_name = 'entries/entry_detail.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this error also, saw that I had a spelling error in urls.py

In my urlpatterns
I had `path ('', AtricleListView.as_view(), name='article-list'),`
instead of `path ('', ArticleListView.as_view(), name='article-list'),`

also in the import `AtricleListView` I had to change it to `ArticleListView`

from this

```
    from .views import (
    AtricleListView
)
```

to this

```
from .views import (
    ArticleListView
)
```

My error looked like this

> ImportError: cannot import name 'AtricleListView' from 'blog.views'

Here you can see that I tried to import "AtricleListView" instead of the real name that was "AtricleListView"